# Generating a time series with a specific start and end date

Tags: r, date, time, range

I want to generate a time series with all business dates in the range:

```
startDate = "1990-01-01"
endDate = "1990-12-31"
```

For example "1990-01-01", "1990-01-02", ...

Answer (score 14):

@csgillespie: `chron` provides the function `is.weekend`:

```
days = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1990-12-31"), by="1 day")
library(chron)
weekDays = days[!is.weekend(days)]

## let's check the result with the function weekdays
weekdays(weekDays)
```

Besides, you can get the same results without `chron` using `format`:

```
isWeekend <- function(x) {format(x, '%w') %in% c(0, 6)}
weekDays2 = days[!isWeekend(days)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the `seq` command. For example,

```
##Specify you want 10 dates starting on 1990-01-01
R> seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), length.out=10, by="1 day")
 [1] "1990-01-01" "1990-01-02" "1990-01-03" "1990-01-04" "1990-01-05"
 [6] "1990-01-06" "1990-01-07" "1990-01-08" "1990-01-09" "1990-01-10"
```

or

```
##Specify the start and end with increment
R> seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1990-01-10"), by="1 day")
 [1] "1990-01-01" "1990-01-02" "1990-01-03" "1990-01-04" "1990-01-05"
 [6] "1990-01-06" "1990-01-07" "1990-01-08" "1990-01-09" "1990-01-10"
```

To just get business days, you can use the `chron` library:

```
days = seq(as.Date("1990-01-01"), as.Date("1990-12-31"), by="1 day")
library(chron)
weekDays = days[!is.weekend(days)]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `base` function called `?weekdays`.

```
startDate = "1990-01-01"
endDate = "1990-12-31"

x <- seq(as.Date(startDate), to = as.Date(endDate), by="1 day")

x[!weekdays(x) %in% c("Sunday", "Saturday")]
```

But, since the actual names of the days will be locale-specific, be sure to set those correctly.

Note that `weekdays` is just a wrapper on `format(x, "%A")`. See `?strptime` for the details on the format codes.